# rspec service objects how to test update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I can't understand, how to test this case. I googled it but didn't find anything.
As a result (i think i am correct) I should expect to return 2 objects with new statuses false because I pass in subject.call id by first object what created in let.
Please someone can help me and explain to me how to test update_all and other update cases. Thanks!

#rspec

```
describe Plans::MakeAllPlansInactive do
  subject do
    described_class.call(plan_id: plan.id)
  end

  let!(:plan) do
    create(:plan, active: true)
  end

  let!(:plan_1) do
    create(:plan, active: true)
  end

  let!(:plan_2) do
    create(:plan, active: true)
  end


  context 'when success' do
    it 'makes one active, other passive' do
      subject.to eq(2)
    end
  end
```

#service

```
def call
  return unless Plan.find(plan_id).active?

  update_our_plans
end

private

def update_our_plans
  Plan.where.not(id: plan_id).update_all(active: false)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this service you obviously are more interested in the side-effect, than return value, so in spec describe what state you are expecting with a test like:

```rb
it 'makes one active, other passive' do
  expect(Plan.count).to eq(3) # just to be sure
  expect{ subject }.to change{ plan_1.reload.active }.from(true).to(false).and(
    change{ plan_2.reload.active }.from(true).to(false)
  ).and(not_change{ plan.reload.active })
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Can you explain what it is reload?

Comment: It reloads the attributes for this object from the database. The service call made the copy of the object in the test stale so you need to reload the attributes from the database.